# AspectJ Pointcut for constructor invocation

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to write an advice to intercept the calls to constructors of a class with my custom annotation:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
public class SomeClass {

   public SomeClass(Foo a, Bar b){
      ...
   }

   public SomeClass(Foo a){
      this(a, null);
   }

}
```

I see an example of how to intercept constructor calls, in general:

```
@Before("execution(*.new(..))")
```

How do I update this to only execute for classes that are annotated with my `@MyCustomAnnotation` annotation

Answer (score 1):

I use this for method invocation:

```
within(@MyCustomAnnotation *)
```

So, the resulting aspect code would be:

```
@Before("execution(*.new(..)) && within(@MyCustomAnnotation *)")
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@MyCustomAnnotation *.new(..))")
```

I am referring to the documentation here: https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/

and, it should work in theory, but I am not having any luck.